# What is the jz element in html?

Tags: html, element

On [this page](http://www.benzinga.com/news/16/08/8334001/elon-musks-solar-ambitions-raise-the-roof), popular ad blocking software *removes* ads near the top and right of the page as may be expected, but *adds* a new section of clickbait ads just below the story, above the "Posted-In" tags, copyright/disclaimer, and "Related Articles" section.  An example of what it looks like is shown below.

After a div containing five spans with the headline "Paid Content" and a float-clearing div, nestled within a few divs with gibberish class names, each clickbait item is in an element like this:

```
<div class="gbcfwaxUasi" id="gbqfwabzip4">
  <div cls="bqfway_avbrott_simule">
    <jz ci="2355" jjr-target="_blank">
      <div class="fa_ew"></div>
      <div class="gbcfwaxUasi_aspect"></div>
      <span class="bweis edlfidr"></span>
      <span class="gbqfway_avbrott gbqfway_avbrott_2355"></span>
      <span class="gbqfway_asg gbqfway_2355"></span>
    </jz>
  </div>
  <span cls="gbqfway_ulv8_box"><span></span>
    <jz ci="2355" jjr-target="_blank">
      <div class="fa_ew"></div>
      <span class="bweis edlfidr"></span>
      <span class="gbqfway_ulv8 gbqfway_frogd">
        US Store Sells Designer Products For Pennies
      </span>
      <span class="gbqfway_asg gbqfway_2355"></span>
    </jz>
  </span>
</div>
```

I could not find the "jz" element (e.g. line 3) anywhere on [this list of HTML elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element), nor on other lists.  **What is it?**  Is this a custom version of HTML (as possibly hinted at by the "cls" attribute in the lines before the jz, which is [nonstandard for div](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div) and [span](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)?)  Does the use of these strange elements/ attributes play a causal role in causing ad blockers to run in reverse and effectively add ads?

*Example Image (hover to show; spoiler-tagged to make this question less spam-looking by default):*

---

> [image: Clickbait ads shown in position]

Comment: It's a made up element. And what's the point of using an adblocker that inserts ads? That's like getting a flu shot that gives you herpes.

Comment: @j08691 because one *didn't know* when installing or using the adblocker that it *adds* ads, and it's one of the most popular ones out there?  Also, I'm not sure that's a good analogy - my impression is that herpes is worse than the flu.  This is more like getting a flu shot that gives you a bruised arm and a cold.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I came across a similar issue using an Ad Blocking Program. But I did take care of it by adding

```
##div.gbcfwaxUasi
```

to my filter list, and that killed of those pesky ads.